# assistence with basic js in order to get skype button to work

Tags: javascript, html

I am relatively new to javascript and trying to link the javascript to a parent div in the html body with out inserting the javascript into the body of the html. Could anyone tell me how to fix it. The end result will be a skype call button to allow users to ring me off a webpage with a click of the skype button thats ment (when working) to appear on the webpage.

### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<!-- skype js script-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<script src="js/skype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- skype parent div-->
  <div id="SkypeButton_Call_eddyrailgun_1">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript

```
Skype.ui({
  "name": "call",
  "element": "SkypeButton_Call_eddyrailgun_1",
  "participants": ["eddyrailgun"],
  "imageSize": 24
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<a href="skype:skype?call">Call me</a>
```

This will open the Skype application.

Comment: So you implying if I was to add a button into my webpage and link the above to it, it would then start a skype call ?

Comment: Yes, if they have Skype open it will start a call, if not it will open Skype and start a call.